# How can I get around IE's 'limitations' when it comes to innerHTML manipulation?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I'm talking about the fact that IE doesn't like stuff like:

```
some_table_element.innerHTML = some_HTML_to_create_dynamic_tables;
```

Is there any way I can go around it so that I don't have to re-write a day's worth of code for it? maybe with jQuery?

I'm working on a table structure that allows the change of whole rows and even tables with one click of a button and I forgot that IE doesn't like it at all

Comment: jQuery, maybe. I hear .html does some black magic voodoo stuff to let you dump markup into a table (or, rewrite it using the DOM, I bet it will be cleaner and less of a maintenance headache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see Eric Vasilik's blog on a work-around:
http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html